# Recommended way of using FastAPI, cx_Oracle and SQLAlchemy for Oracle Stored Procedures?

Tags: python, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy, fastapi, cx-oracle

I'm following the FastAPI docs and I'm having a hard time figuring out how can I call a oracle stored procedure.

This is the code I have so far:

**main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from ansimarkup import ansiprint as print
import cx_Oracle
import os

from api.utils.dependencies import get_connection
import api.core.database

app = FastAPI()

@app.on_event("startup")
def startup():
  print(f"<b><cyan>[APP]</cyan></b>:    Application ready!")


@app.on_event("shutdown")
def shutdown():
  print(f"<b><cyan>[APP]</cyan></b>:    Shutting down")


@app.get('/')
def index(conn = Depends(get_connection)):
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  ref_cursor = conn.cursor()
  cursor.callproc("myprocedure", (ref_cursor, 112233))
  for row in ref_cursor:
    print(row)
```

**dependencies.py**

```
from api.core.database import Engine

def get_connection():
  try:
    conn = Engine.raw_connection()
    yield conn
  finally:
    conn.close()
```

**database.py**

```
import os
import cx_Oracle
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from ansimarkup import ansiprint as print
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

load_dotenv(verbose=True)

cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=os.environ.get('ORACLE_CLIENT'))

print(f"<b><cyan>[APP]</cyan></b>:    Connecting to database <cyan>. 
{os.environ.get('ORACLE_CONNECT_STRING')}</cyan>")

pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(
  user=os.environ.get('ORACLE_USER'),
  password=os.environ.get('ORACLE_PASS'),
  dsn=os.environ.get('ORACLE_CONNECT_STRING'),
  min=int(os.environ.get('ORACLE_POOL_SIZE')),
  max=int(os.environ.get('ORACLE_POOL_SIZE')),
  increment=0,
  threaded=True,
  getmode=cx_Oracle.SPOOL_ATTRVAL_WAIT
)

Engine = create_engine("oracle://", creator=pool.acquire, poolclass=NullPool)
```

I already have the stored procedures from the current version of the project, that is mode using nodejs, how can I call the procedures, get the out cursor and iterate through the results?

**EDIT:**

On `database.py` I changed the **Engine** variable to be public, so I could import it on `dependecies.py` and get a connection for every request made. Then on `main.py` I'm using the same **Depends** function from FastPAI to get the connection and then extracting the cursor from it. Do you think that this is a good approach to follow? Will I need to close the cursor after the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly get the raw connection `connection = engine.raw_connection()` and then use cx_Oracle calls as shown in [`ref_cursor.py`](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/ref_cursor.py).  For example:

```
"""

create or replace procedure myrefcursorproc (
    p_startingvalue                     number,
    p_endingvalue                       number,
    p_refcursor                         out sys_refcursor
) as
begin
    open p_refcursor for
        select first_name || ' ' || last_name
        from employees
        where employee_id between p_startingvalue and p_endingvalue;
end;
/
show errors

"""

import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
import sys
import os

if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=os.environ.get("HOME")+"/Downloads/instantclient_19_8")

# If using cx_Oracle < 8.2 then add options threaded=True, encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8"
pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(user="cj", password="secrent", dsn="localhost/orclpdb1",
                             min=4, max=4, increment=0)


engine = create_engine("oracle://", creator=pool.acquire, poolclass=NullPool, max_identifier_length=128)

connection = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()
ref_cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.callproc("myrefcursorproc", (102, 105, ref_cursor))
for row in ref_cursor:
    print(row)
```

I'm not sure how this maps through to FastAPI.

Comment: Hi Christopher, thank you for your answer. I'm editing my code with some tweaks, please take a look again.